# Any way to make this more efficient? Tenable API report call

Tags: python, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a script that does a bunch of data manipulation, but it is getting bottlenecked by this function.

The length of the Tenable generator array `ips` is always around 1000, give or take. The length of `ips[row]` is 5.

Are there any improvements that I can make here to make things more efficient? I feel like this takes far longer than it should.

```
def get_ten(sc):
    now = time.time()
    ips = [sc.analysis.vulns(('ip', '=', ip), tool='sumseverity', sortDirection='desc') for ip in [x[15] for x in csv.reader(open('full.csv', 'r'))
     if x[15] != 'PrivateIpAddress']]
    row = 0
    while row < len(ips):
        scan_data = []
        scan_count = 0
        for scan in ips[row]:
            count = scan['count']
            scan_data.append(count)
            scan_count += int(count)
        row += 1
    print(time.time() - now)
```

Output: `2702.747463464737`

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about Tenable, but it seems that `sc.analysis.vulns` sends requests to some API, am I right? If that is the case, perhaps asynchronous programming could be the answer. Do you know if Tenable provides asynchronous functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try inversing your logic.

From looking at your code, it looks like you currently:

1. Read a CSV to get IPs.
2. Call the sc.analysis API for each IP
3. Process the results

My best guess is that the majority of the time is taken sending out the API calls and then waiting for the results. Instead I suggest you try:

1. Call sc.analysis API (without filtering ip) and read the results to get all IPs (as a set?)
2. Read CSV and get IPs as another set.
3. Do set union operation to find vulnerable IP addresses.

Comment: The call actually uses each ip as a lookup, so to speak, to grab a specific report. I wouldn't be able to do the call without the IP.

Comment: There was nothing in [API docs](https://pytenable.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sc.html#tenable.sc.analysis.AnalysisAPI.vulns) suggesting IP is required. If possible I suggest you try it to see if you can get multiple pages result. Otherwise since I don't have teneble access I can't help any more than this. If you must do call-by-call for IP, then you must do multiprocessing/threading or async suggestion from @ruencomelli.